# Need assistance duplicating the parallax effect on Ringly.com

Tags: parallax

about half way down on this page there is a great parallax scroll effect where just the screen of the phone appears to be changing and the background moves but the phone stays static.  I'm not sure what it's called so i don't know hat to search for.  Does anyone have more examples of this or can show where some tutorials to do this might be?